# BIML CDCSpliter component

Tags: ssis-2012, cdc, biml

Here is the code for my Custom CDCSplitter component

```html
 <CustomComponent Name="CDCSplitter"
                    ComponentClassId="{874F7595-FB5F-40FF-96AF-FBFF8250E3EF}"
                    ComponentTypeName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.CdcSplitterComponent, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                    ContactInfo="Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;"
                    UsesDispositions="true"
                    Version="2"
                    ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
                  <Annotations>
                    <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Directs a stream of net change records into different outputs based on the type of the change (Insert, Delete and Update). This allows specific handling for different types of change records.</Annotation>
                  </Annotations>
                  <InputPaths>
                    <InputPath Identifier="Input" OutputPathName="CDCSource.Output">
                      <InputColumns>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$start_lsn" />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$operation" />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$update_mask" />
                         <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>" />
                       <# } #>
                      </InputColumns>
                    </InputPath>
                  </InputPaths>
                  <OutputPaths>
                    <OutputPath Name="InsertOutput">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Insert.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >0</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" />
                        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                       <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns /> 
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="UpdateOutput">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Update.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >1</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" />
                         <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                      <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="DeleteOutput">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Delete.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >2</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" />
                        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>"/>
                       <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="ErrorOutput" IsErrorOutput="true">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Error.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >3</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$start_lsn" DataType="Binary" Length="10" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$operation" DataType="Int32" />
                        <OutputColumn Name="__$update_mask" DataType="Binary" Length="128" />
                        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <OutputColumn Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="<#=column.DataType#>" Length="<#=column.Length#>" />
                        <# } #>
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns />
                    </OutputPath>

                  </OutputPaths>


                </CustomComponent>
```

This Biml code compiles without error but when I execute the package It throws 
 following error :

Error: 0xC0047062 at DFT Incremental load_Source1, CDCSplitter [92]: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSBuffer100.DirectRow(Int32 hRow, Int32 lOutputID)
   at Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.CdcSplitterComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 inputId, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)
Error: 0xC0047022 at DFT Incremental load_Source1, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "CDCSplitter" (92) failed with error code 0x80070057 while processing input "CDCSource_Output_CDCSplitter" (94). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Biml Experts Please give suggestions to deal with this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,I am sharing for others if anyone face the same problem

Rewrite the above BIML code to

```html
<CustomComponent Name="CDCSplitter"
                    ComponentClassId="{874F7595-FB5F-40FF-96AF-FBFF8250E3EF}"
                    ComponentTypeName="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.CdcSplitterComponent, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                    ContactInfo="Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;"
                    UsesDispositions="true"
                    Version="1"
                    ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
                  <Annotations>
                    <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Directs a stream of net change records into different outputs based on the type of the change (Insert, Delete and Update). This allows specific handling for different types of change records.</Annotation>
                  </Annotations>
                  <InputPaths>
                    <InputPath Identifier="Input" OutputPathName="CDCSource.Output" >
                      <InputColumns>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$start_lsn"  />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$operation"   />
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="__$update_mask" />
                         <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
                        <InputColumn SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>"  />
                       <# } #>
                      </InputColumns>
                    </InputPath>
                  </InputPaths>
                  <OutputPaths>
                    <OutputPath Name="InsertOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Insert.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >0</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                      <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns /> 
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="UpdateOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Update.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >1</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                       <OutputColumns>
                       
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="DeleteOutput" SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Delete.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >2</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                        <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                    </OutputPath>

                    <OutputPath Name="ErrorOutput" IsErrorOutput="true"  SynchronousInput="Input" ExclusionGroup="1">
                      <Annotations>
                        <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Output type - Error.</Annotation>
                      </Annotations>
                      <CustomProperties>
                        <CustomProperty Name="OutputType" DataType="Int32"
                                        TypeConverter="Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit.OutputType, Attunity.SqlServer.CDCSplit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa342389a732e31c"
                                    >3</CustomProperty>
                      </CustomProperties>
                       <OutputColumns>
                      
                      </OutputColumns>
                      <ExternalColumns />
                    </OutputPath>

                  </OutputPaths>


                </CustomComponent>
```